# Single target group for multiple services - ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, target, aws-application-load-balancer

I have 10 services which are running on a diff-diff port on ECS, I have to implement blue/green deployment with an application load balancer on ECS. I have two scenarios:

1. Needs to be created 20 Target Group as per services(blue and green target groups) -- I wonder
   if this will be complicated.
2. or can I create a rules in a particular
   listener where I can define the path (port) base routing -- not sure
   about this.

What things can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Each target group is only for a single port. You will have to create multiple target groups.

Comment: So what you are saying is 20 in total target groups - 10 from blue and 10 for green ?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that you need two target groups for each port. I know it seems ugly but if you are using something like CloudFormation or Terraform it shouldn't be a big deal.